# Login Failed for user "sa" on SQL Server 2000 database using Linq-To-SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2000

I can connect with the sa user via Enterprise Manager and Query Analyzer. I created the `.dbml` file and connection string in Visual Studio 2008 then manually imported it into the Visual Studio 2010 ASP.Net MVC3 project.

I was under the impression that this was an accepted way to work with a SQL Server 2000 database in VS 2010.

I have copied the connection string to the Web.config in the ASP.Net website.
[Here is the stack trace](https://gist.github.com/3415588)

I'm not sure what the problem is at all. I'm hoping that it ISN'T because VS 2010 projects will NEVER be able to connect to a SQL Server 2000.

**EDIT**
Connection string is

```
<add name="MobiledbConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=JAMESWRIGHT2771\SQLLOCAL;Initial Catalog=mobiledb;User ID=sa;Password=MYPASSHERE"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Obviously `MYPASSHERE` is where my password goes.

Comment: The problem is in your stack trace: `Login failed for user 'sa'`.  SQL is telling you the password is wrong (or access is disabled, or something similar).  So you **are** connecting to the SQL server.  Is it possible the password was encrypted in the web.config previously?

Comment: Nope, the password is correct in the Web.config and not encrypted.

Comment: VS 2010 can *definitely* use SQL Server 2000 - no problem (other than that SQL Server version being really old and creaky and lacking tons of useful features....)

Comment: Can you please **show us** the connection string you're using?

Comment: @marc_s : Updated with connection string.

Comment: fyi - you're less than 8 months away from the official end of life for sql server 2000 (April 8,2013) After that point, they won't even patch critical security issues any more. In other words, it's time to start moving to at minimum Sql Server 2005 _now_.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn : I am definitely aware of that and have advised those above me but the decision is out of my hands.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's related and perhaps a bit late but I added the option 'Persist Security Info=True' to my connection string and it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the communications haven't changed -- it is quite backwards compatible. What you might try and do within the database changed quite a bit though. IE, linq to sql's schema generation might do some things that Sql 2000 doesn't like unless it has a compatibility mode for that model.

You will often get this error when the database you are accessing does not exist. Have you created it yet?

Comment: Yes the database is created, and Linq to SQL was released when SQL Server 2000 was still in heavy use so it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, though I've never dealt with this thing before.
When I import the dbml file into VS 2010 it is being put into a "Class Library" project and for some reason it is using the Connection String that is in a "Settings.settings" file and NOT the one in the app.config or Web.config files (I verified by completely removing the Web.config and app.config Connection Strings).

I have never heard of this Settings.settings file, but I have it working at the moment by changing that value.